# how to omit a commit while squashing

Tags: git

I have 3 commits and i want to skip a commit -2 while rebasing into 1
say

```
commit -1
commit -2 
commit -3
```

i did git rebase -i HEAD~3

```
pick commit -1
pick commit -2
squash commit -3
```

i tried like this  (removed the pick commit -2) but that deleted the commit -2 itself from git log :(

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
pick commit -1
squash commit -3
```

Someone please help me how can i squash commit 1 and commit 3 using command only.

Comment: When you say "skip commit 2" you mean you want to squash 3 into 1 and leave commit 2 in the history after the squashed 1+3?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, just reorder the commits:

```
pick commit -1
squash commit -3
pick commit -2
```

This would place `commit -2` after `-1` and `-3`; put `-2` on top if you want it to come before.  (Commits are evaluated top to bottom.)

Answer (score 2):

Easy, reorder the lines:

```
pick 1
squash 3
pick 2
```

This will rebase the history squashing 3 into 1 and moving commit 2 after.

From the help text:

> These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.

```
# Rebase 25c328e..a038737 onto 25c328e (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the history of the branch and the commits; you can start a branch from commit-4; cherry pick 1 and 3, squash them and then cherry pick commit-2. You will be on a new branch but it will have the end result you need. Also, I assumed the commits would not have conflicts.

```
    commit-1
    commit-2 
    commit-3
    commit-4

git checkout commit-4 
git checkout -b newbranch name
git cherry-pick commit-3 commit-1
git rebase and do the squash
git cherry-pick commit-2
```